# How to include an IP packet in C linux sockets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip, tunneling

I want to include an IP packet in Socket programming. I have a readymade Ip packet which contains igmp packet. I don't want to design igmp protocol but want to use that packet to sent igmp query. By some how the Ip packet  I have must be recognize as IP packet and not as TCP/UDP data.

Comment: I think you're going to have to do a *lot* better job of explaining your question if you want an answer.

Comment: Ok lets give one more try......  Normally in tcp/udp sockets, if we receive those packets through socket programming, we get the protocol included as tcp/udp. Now I want to send IP packet instead of tcp or udp and the protocol field(of the outermost IP packet) also should indicate that the protocol included is IP. In short I want IP with in IP or Ip encapsulation.....  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [the raw socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw) with [sendmsg](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendmsg).  This need `root` permission.

Comment: Or the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability, `sudo execcap 'cap_net_raw=ep' app`

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to send IGMP packets you should use the setsockopt() API to do so.